# Shorthand for group by all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 15 columns with customer info and I want to join the sum of their purchases onto the table. I am currently attempting the following join:

```
SELECT  A.*, SUM(B.SALES_AMT) AS SALES
FROM CUST_INFO A
LEFT JOIN SALES_TABLE B
ON A.Cust_ID = B.Cust_ID
GROUP BY fooa, foob, fooc, etc
```

Is there a way to group by where I can simply say `GROUP BY A.*` instead of having to write out all 15 or so columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the sum into an *apply*:

```
select  A.*, Isnull(B.SALES, 0) SALES
from CUST_INFO A
outer apply (
  select Sum(B.SALES_AMT) SALES
  from SALES_TABLE B
  where B.Cust_ID = A.Cust_ID
)B;
```

Comment: your solution worked, but how does an outer apply work?

Comment: [sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Answer (score 2):

Group your sales data in a sub-query

```
SELECT A.*, B.SALES
FROM CUST_INFO A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT B.Cust_ID, SUM(B.SALES_AMT) SALES
  FROM SALES_TABLE B
  GROUP BY B.Cust_ID
) B ON A.Cust_ID = B.Cust_ID;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY A.Cust_ID` in theory shouldn't be necessary assuming it's the primary key which seems likely